# Given a nilpotent operator $L$ in a certain space, can we always find another space such that $L$ is not nilpotent?

Tags: linear-algebra, nilpotence

I just thought the following (perhaps silly) observation: If we have D, the differentiation operator in the space of polynomials of $\deg \leq n$, then $D$ is nilpotent. But if we consider a space such as the space spanned by $\{ e^x\}$, then $D$ won't be nilpotent. So being nilpotent depends not only on the operator, it also depends on the space it acts.

- Given a nilpotent operator $L$ in a certain space, can we always find another space such that $L$ is not nilpotent?
- Given a non-nilpotent operator $L$ in a certain space, can we always find another space in which the $L$ is nilpotent?

Comment: In a different space, it's not the same operator.

Comment: Notice that if $P_n$ is the space of polynomials of degree $\leq n$, then $e^x \in P_\infty$ of which $P_n$, $n \leq\infty$, is a subspace.

Comment: If a non-nilpotent operator $L$ is given on a space $V$ then its restriction to the subspace $\{0\}\subset V$ is trivially nilpotent, but it seems unlikely that the question can be answered in a satisfactory way since it is in general not clear how the operator is defined on "another space"